# Writing Tests for Tauri Commands: How to Access and Manage State in Test Environments

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, tauri

lets say I have a state and a command like this

```
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MyState {
  pub s: std::sync::Mutex<String>,
  pub t: std::sync::Mutex<std::collections::HashMap<String, String>>,
}

#[tauri::command]
fn hello_world(state: tauri::State<'_, MyState>) -> String {
  let mut s = state.s.lock().unwrap();
  s.push_str(" world");
  s.clone()
}
```

How do I access `MyState` when I want to write a test for `hello_world` function?

I haven't attempted any specific actions yet as I'm currently exploring how to approach testing for the `hello_world` function in `Tauri`. I'm seeking guidance on the correct methodology to access and manipulate the `MyState` struct within the testing environment. Could you provide assistance on how to effectively set up and conduct tests for `Tauri` commands involving state management?

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled with this myself. There is a "hidden" unstable feature called `tauri::test`, which, as far as I can tell, is virtually undocumented in the user docs, but it's documented in the reference on docs.rs.

You can see some examples here: [docs.rs documentation](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/test/index.html), a [snippet](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/blob/091100acbb507b51de39fb1446f685926f888fd2/examples/api/src-tauri/src/lib.rs#L163) from the examples.

Because I also need it, I set up a small application with a working test [here](https://github.com/tachyonicbytes/so-answers/tree/63ef7a8ed7a19afb7891f3ba3548b5c30646f8de/77524788/tauri-app). Shortly:

Add the `test` feature in your `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
tauri = { version = "1.4", features = ["test"] }
```

You can now use `tauri::test` for setting up your mock application:

```rs
fn create_app<R: tauri::Runtime>(mut builder: tauri::Builder<R>) -> tauri::App<R> {
    builder
        .setup(|app| {Ok(())})
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![greet])
        .build(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("failed to build app")
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use tauri::Manager;
    #[test]
    fn something() {
        let data = r#"{"name": "the test"}"#;
        let app = super::create_app(tauri::test::mock_builder());
        let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();
        tauri::test::assert_ipc_response(
            &window,
            tauri::InvokePayload {
                cmd: "greet".into(),
                tauri_module: None,
                callback: tauri::api::ipc::CallbackFn(0),
                error: tauri::api::ipc::CallbackFn(1),
                inner: serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap(),
            },
            Ok("Hello, the test! You've been greeted from Rust!"),
        );
    }
}
```

If you want to test on my repo, simply install the app as usual and then run the tests:

```bash
pnpm install
cd src-tauri
cargo test
```

Remember that you won't test that the serialization is done correctly from the javascript side. For that, you will need end-to-end tests, which, fortunately, are in the user documentation.

Please let me know if this is enough for you. I know I didn't add a `State` example per-se, I can add a `State` example as well.